# How can I configure multiple authentication managers depending on the incoming URL for an authorization server?

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

**With Spring Security <5.2**

In a legacy project, for a password grant scenario, I need to configure an authorization server.

Currently it is done extending `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`, and the authorization endpoints are configured overriding the `configure(AuthorizationEndpointsServerConfigurer)` method.

My problem is that this configurer takes one `AuthenticationManager` for the password grant, when I would need something like an `AuthenticationManagerResolver` (**but I can't upgrade to 5.2**) to be able to apply a different authentication depending on the incoming URL (an authentication manager for admin URLs, e.g. "/admin/**", and another one for non-admin).

How can I do that? I can change the approach, but again I can't upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing your own Delegating`AuthenticationManager`, inject the list of your `AuthenticationManager`s in it, and put your logic in `authenticate` method. E.g:

```java
@Component("delegatingAM")
public class DelegatingAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {
    private final List<AuthenticationManager> ams;

    @Autowire
    public DelegatingAuthenticationManager(@Qualifier("x") AuthenticationManager amX, @Qualifier("y") AuthenticationManager amY) {
        this.ams = List.of(amX, amY); // Arrays.asList(amX, amY);
        // you can inject variables for your conditions here 
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
         if (...) this.ams.get(0).authenticate(authentication);
         if (...) this.ams.get(0).authenticate(authentication);
         // Or you can loop over the list like AuthenticationManager is implemented with AuthenticatioProvider
    }
}
```

Then inject it to `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("delegatingAM")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope it will help, for the worse case, you could start to think about using many AuthorizationServer`SecurityFilterChain`s, one `AuthenticationManager` for each. And based on the URL, direct the request to the right `SecurityFilterChain`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, how would you access the request to be able to write the if condition to choose the right manager?

Comment: And about the other solution you mentioned, would you have an example? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot the most important part that the conditions are on the request. About the second way, ideally, it's the best fit for your case following the spring security theory, but I haven't tried this before, I only had 3 `SecurityFilterChain`s each for Basic, Oauth, Saml2 when I was doing with this legacy project in the past instead of 2 Oauth as your case. So sorry again. Hope anyone else can help you, good luck!

Comment: It could be great if you could change the predefined `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration` or find something to configure `HttpSecurity#requestMatchers`, that's the key in order to create 2 or more `SecurityFilterChain` in your application.